# login form in the layout: is there any specific controller part related to the layout?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a layout with a login form.

Where should i write the controller code for that login form? In every actions where the layout is shown? (I dont think so..) Is there any specific controller part related to the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply create a specific action where you'll handle the login form submissions, create a route for it, and point the login form to that route.

Then in that action you can make use of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` and after the successful login redirect the user back where he came from. From the outside it won't be noticeable, that the user is going to another page, and you don't have to put the code to every action using the layout.